# N2CMS - Missing Prepare_Dependencies-vs2008.bat

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, content-management-system, n2, n2cms

I am attempting to run the sample project for N2CMS.

This is required in order to run the project, but the file appears to be missing.  However, my VS2008 solution file shows it.  What could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator responded to my post at: http://n2cms.codeplex.com/discussions/250568